# Converting to Swift 3 (Swift and Firebase Project)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift3

I have just updated my Xcode to Xcode8 and I have converted the project to swift 3.

In signIn function here:

```
  Firth. Auth()?.signIn(withEmail: self.EmailTF.text!, password: self.PasswordTF.text!, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error: NSError?) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        } else {

                           self.ref.child("UserProfile").child(user!.uid).setValue([
                                "email": self.EmailTF.text!,
                                "name" : self.NameTF.text!,
                                "phone": self.PhoneTF.text!,
                                "city" : self.CityTF.text!,
                                ])
                            print("Sucess")

                        }
                    })
```

I'm getting this error:

```
cannot convert value of type '(FIRUser?, NSError?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'FIRAuthResultCallback?'
```

What's the replacement of it in swift 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace it with :-

```
 FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail:self.EmailTF.text!, password: self.PasswordTF.text!, completion: { (user, err) in
       if let error = err {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {

                       self.ref.child("UserProfile").child(user!.uid).setValue([
                            "email": self.EmailTF.text!,
                            "name" : self.NameTF.text!,
                            "phone": self.PhoneTF.text!,
                            "city" : self.CityTF.text!,
                            ])
                        print("Sucess")

                    }
    })
```

Comment: May use trailing notation. This makes it simpler to read. `.signIn(withEmail: "dasd", password: "qwewqe"){...}` https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102

Comment: Great, thanks for the note! Will check the link out.

Comment: @Mariah No this should work fine.@BennX what are you exactly trying to say here? To use `completionBlocks:`? Where? This is a predefined Firebase Auth function. Sorry i just didn't get you.. Please elaborate

Comment: Just checked , its working fine for me..Also try `name.text != ""` if you are trying to check wether the textField is empty