# xcode 8 swift 3 errors Google authenthications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have everything great just this code is giving me an error:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: {(user: FIRUser?, error: NSError?) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
```

Is there a way to fix it? It'll help me log in users using Google just need a fix.

Comment: Please provide error log.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '(FIRUser?, NSError?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'FIRAuthResultCallback?'

Comment: Is your project in Swift 2 OR  Swift 3 ?

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562585/converting-to-swift-3-swift-and-firebase-project

Comment: swift 3 im using Xcode 8 swift 3

Comment: FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: {(user: FIRUser?, error: NSError?) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }else {